# Date error in GetPivotData in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have a row with dates, 2018-01-01, 2018-02-01 ... 2020-12-01, that I want to reference to, from a GETPIVOTDATA formula.

I've managed to reference to another cells for Gross Profit, AM, Region, and Team, but can't figure out the Month.

`GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of Gross Profit]";$BD$4;"[Data].[AM]";"[Data].[AM].&["&$A$4&"]";"[Data].[Month]";"[Data].[Month].&[2018-01-01T00:00:00]";"[Data].[Region]";"[Data].[Region].&["&$A$1&"]";"[Data].[Team]";"[Data].[Team].&["&$A$2&"]")`

I believe it has something to do with T00:00:00 but don't know what to do in the formula.

Comment: what's exactly wrong with your formula? getting wrong results? error message? what exactly? can you please also post one of the working formulas?

Comment: I get #REF. This is a formula w/o any changes. I want to change the item in the formula.  GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of Gross Profit]";$BD$4;"[Data].[AM]";"[Data].[AM].&[RFR]";"[Data].[Month]";"[Data].[Month].&[2018-01-01T00:00:00]";"[Data].[Region]";"[Data].[Region].&[APAC]";"[Data].[Team]";"[Data].[Team].&[ANZA]")

Comment: Please provide a sample about this problem.